# Meteor.deps.Context and Invalid Collection of Documents

Tags: meteor

What's the difference with the following two blocks of code? The top works as expect, but the bottom does not.

```
// Initially outputs 0, but eventually outputs the # of players.
Meteor.autorun(function() {
  var players = Players.find();
  console.info(players.count());
});

// Outputs 0 twice. Why does this not work like the block above?
var players = Players.find();
Meteor.autorun(function() {
  console.info(players.count());
});
```

I'm testing this in the leaderboard example, within the Meteor.isClient block.

Thank you,
Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Meteor is reactive you need to make your query within a reactive context a.k.a the `Meteor.autorun`. The reactive contexts are: `Template`, `Meteor.autorun`, `Meteor.render` and `Meteor.renderList`.

In the second case `var players = Players.find();` is run while Meteor is starting up, and contains the data it got while querying at that time, while starting up.

In the first you've placed the query in a reactive context. Which is recalled and rerun whenever there is a data update of a sort. In the second case it doesn't get a chance to rerun the query it it remains with the data contained while the browser just loaded the page up.

While Meteor is reactive you still need to re query the data within the reactive context.

Comment: Why am I able to do `var players = Players.find(); Template.leaderboard.players = function() { return players; };` How does the Template re-query the data?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think it has something to with the cursor is lazy and fetches the data in a template context, if I append `.fetch()` anywhere (in the the `Meteor.autorun` or the initial var statement it won't work in template as well.

Comment: Looking at the spark code (meteor's templating system) it looks like the cursor is made observable which is why it works with a template provided a cursor is returned by the template helper

Comment: Thank you @Akshat. I was just reviewing the spark.js file and will continue reviewing the spark package as you have confirmed this is where I should be looking.